# What is the graph API of pages to get followers, liked & messenger interacted list of users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm new to this area, so excuse me if this question sounds silly. I'm looking for pages (or similar) API endpoint that fetches me the list of users that liked, followed, messaged, posted or made any form of interaction (even visiting) a page. I checked at 'pages/insights' - now I don't know how to pass 'parameters' to it. I passed 'v9.0/pageid/insights?metric={_unique}' but no response (I'm pretty sure I'm not making a right api call). Any thoughts or guidance on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a pages callback API to get page likes, comments etc but works on pages that are approved. Also, the messenger APIs works only for the admin, testers and developers until the page is finally approval. Pages/insights api doesn't serve this purpose